# StreamReader not reading japanese characters from csv file

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, fastercsv

Reading csv file using stream reader with fields in double quotes of Japanese characters. Its not reading Japanese characters and taking it as unicode characters. I tried different encoding types but its not working for me. Please share me some idea or some other solution to tackle this issue. Or is there a better way to do it.

```
public DataTable ReadDataFromCSV(string path, char delim)
{
    string fulltext;
    string[] arrColumnNames;
    string[] arrColumnValues;
    string[] arrRows;
    int i, j, n;

    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    DataRow row;
    if (delim.ToString().Length < 1)
    {
        delim = ',';
    }
    try
    {
        //' check that the file exists before opening it
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (TextReader sr = new StreamReader(path,Encoding.UTF8))
            {
            fulltext = sr.ReadToEnd();
            arrRows = fulltext.Split('\n');
            arrColumnNames = arrRows[0].Replace('"', ' ').Trim().Split(delim);
            //'add columns to a datatable
            for (n = 0; n < arrColumnNames.Length - 1; n++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(arrColumnNames[n], System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
            }//next
            for (i = 1; i < arrRows.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                arrColumnValues = arrRows[i].Replace('"', ' ').Trim().Split(delim);
                row = dt.NewRow();
                for (j = 0; j < (arrColumnNames.Length - 1); j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!(arrColumnValues[j] == null))
                        {
                            row[arrColumnNames[j]] =                      arrColumnValues[j].Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row[arrColumnNames[j]] = "";
                        }//End If
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Write("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }//next
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }//next

        }
        }//End if
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
    }

    finally
    {

    }//End Try

    return dt;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What encoding types did you use? Japanese characters can not be encoded in an ASCII string. Any clue how many there are? More than 4000 IIRC. No way to do that in 1 byte ascii. WHich means either the file is pure garbage, or it is not ASCII at all but  some kind of UNICODE.

Comment: @TomTom: It should be noted that the OP does not state anywhere they assume the file to be ASCII-encoded; in fact, they do set `Encoding.UTF8` as the encoding of the reader. (Obviously, that's still not the encoding of the file, but it already fulfils your suggestion of assuming "not ASCII at all but some kind of UNICODE".)

Comment: I too don't get @TomTom comment, why bring ascii into this discussion? .NET doesn't default to ascii even if he hadn't specified it and there's no reason to think someone working with japanese characters would be thinking the file is ASCII?

Comment: Neo, it would be easier if you could provide the file so that we can reproduce this. Also what language is your OS in / does it have japanese installed? (Maybe it's reading the file right but visual studio doesn't have the character set available for rendering?)

Comment: CSV per standard are not Unicode encoded, in acase anyone has not realized it. Unicode / UTF standard also calls for a prefix (byte order mark) which seems to be missing in the file. Which means that IF the file contains Unicode encoded elements, it is - ah - not validly encoded. See http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2002-m04/0064.html for some basics about how UTF works by standard.

Comment: @TomTom: The file you linked to explicitly states "UTF-8 does not require a BOM". Hence, your statement that the file is automatically "not validly encoded" just because it does not have a BOM despite being Unicode-encoded, is incorrect.

Comment: @TomTom: Concerning the claim "CSV per standard are not Unicode encoded", please provide a source. [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) does not impose any specific encoding; the closest thing it says is "Common usage of CSV is US-ASCII" (and that remark appears only connected to MIME types), which obviously does not imply that the OP's file cannot be Unicode-encoded (evem less so without knowing the application it originated from).

Comment: Also bear in mind that the Visual Studio Text Visualizer uses Windows-1252 encoding NOT Unicode to show any text, hence the replacement with interesting characters like '?' when viewing Unicode.

Comment: Encoding encodingShift_Jis = Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis"); using (TextReader sr = new StreamReader(path,encodingShift_Jis)){

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of diamonds visible in your screenshots so the only thing that's crystal is that the text file is **not** encoded in utf-8.  You should very strongly consider getting in touch with the programmer that generated the file and ask for a fix.  Not using a Unicode encoding these days, particularly for a language like Japanese which has many encodings, none of them dominant, is a huge mistake.  It was so bad that the language got its [own word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) for the misery it caused.

Possibilities:

- 932: Shift-JIS on Windows
- 20932, 51932: EUC on Unix
- 50220, 50221, 50222: ISO 2022
- several EBCDIC code pages, none you should put up with.

Comment: Thanks a lot the text was Shift-JIS encoded